# JavaFX bindings not passing on values

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

In the past I've used the following support class to wrap an existing `ObservableValue` with one that fires changes on the FX event thread...  and this works fine.

```
class AsyncBinding<T> implements ObservableValue<T> {
    private List<InvalidationListener> invalidationListeners = new ArrayList<>(1);
    private List<ChangeListener<? super T>> changeListeners = new ArrayList<>(1);
    private ObservableValue<T> original;
    private ChangeListener<T> changeListener;
    private InvalidationListener invalidationListener;
    public AsyncBinding(ObservableValue<T> original) {
        super();
        this.original = original;
        changeListener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            Runnable job = () -> {
                for (ChangeListener<? super T> listener : changeListeners) {
                    listener.changed(obs, oldValue, newValue);
                }
            };
            Platform.runLater(job);
        };
        original.addListener(changeListener);
        invalidationListener = obs -> {
            Runnable job = () -> {
                for (InvalidationListener listener : invalidationListeners) {
                    listener.invalidated(obs);
                }
            };
            Platform.runLater(job);
        };
        original.addListener(invalidationListener);
    }
    @Override
    public void addListener(InvalidationListener arg0) {
        invalidationListeners.add(arg0);
    }
    @Override
    public void removeListener(InvalidationListener arg0) {
        invalidationListeners.remove(arg0);
    }
    @Override
    public void addListener(ChangeListener<? super T> arg0) {
        changeListeners.add(arg0);
    }
    @Override
    public void removeListener(ChangeListener<? super T> arg0) {
        changeListeners.remove(arg0);

    }
    @Override
    public T getValue() {
        return original.getValue();
    }
}
```

However, if it is used with an intermediate `StringBinding` it stops updating. The following cases show the different behaviour. I've ruled out garbage collection. I'm just after an explanation/understanding of the different behaviours.

### Case 1 - property -> async -> label. Works fine.

```
public class Case1 extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    // hold references to prevent garbage collection...
    private AsyncBinding<String> asyncValue;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Label label = new Label();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(label));
        primaryStage.show();

        ObjectProperty<String> property = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        asyncValue = new AsyncBinding<>(property);

        label.textProperty().bind(asyncValue);

        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
                property.set("a" + i);
            }
        }, "background").start();
    }
}
```

### Case 2 - property -> string -> async -> label. Stops updating randomly...

```
public class Case2 extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    // hold references to prevent garbage collection...
    private StringBinding stringBinding;
    private AsyncBinding<String> asyncValue;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Label label = new Label();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(label));
        primaryStage.show();

        ObjectProperty<String> property = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        stringBinding = Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
            return "b" + property.get();
        }, property);

        asyncValue = new AsyncBinding<>(stringBinding);

        label.textProperty().bind(asyncValue);

        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
                property.set("a" + i);
            }
        }, "background").start();
    }
}
```

### Case 3 - property -> async -> string -> label. Works fine.

```
public class Case3 extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    // hold references to prevent garbage collection...
    private StringBinding stringBinding;
    private AsyncBinding<String> asyncValue;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Label label = new Label();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(label));
        primaryStage.show();

        ObjectProperty<String> property = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        asyncValue = new AsyncBinding<>(property);

        stringBinding = Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
            return "b" + property.get();
        }, asyncValue);

        label.textProperty().bind(stringBinding);

        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
                property.set("a" + i);
            }
        }, "background").start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems unnecessary to me. `ObservableValue` changes should already be on the JavaFX thread.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Depends on the `ObservableValue`. Properties of elements of the gui are updated on the JavaFX application thread. However if you use a model that is modified from a thread doing network communication you may want to use something like the code in the question to do the updates to the gui on the JavaFX application thread.

Comment: The constructor of AsyncBinding was probably not meant to be private.

Comment: I can't explain why this is working in some cases but not in others, but I think there is a fundamental problem overall: JavaFX properties are designed to be single threaded. Access to the underlying value is not synchronized, and the variable representing that value is not `volatile`. In all these examples, you modify the underlying value on the background thread, but access it on the FX Application thread, so you are sharing mutable data across threads with no synchronization. There is actually no guarantee this will *ever* work. (See *Effective Java* Item 66 (in the 2nd ed).)

Comment: In my (limited) testing, all three Cases work as expected (count to 1_000_000). I did have to put a `Thread.sleep(1)` before `property.set("a"+i)`, because otherwise the graphics update could not keep up and I´d see large jumps. Am I correct in assuming the output you see is a very qiuck Counter displaying every integer? Also note, it seems you are using Java 9 while I am testing Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some checks I found out that the problem seems to be caused by the fact that after some time java creates a local copy of the `AsyncBinding.original` binding for the background thread. The background thread keeps updating it's local copy but the value for the JavaFX application thread remains unmodified.

To fix this you could use the value you get in the `ChangeListener` and assign it to a field. Return this value from the `getValue` method instead:

```
// field with updated value on the javafx application thread
private T value;

public AsyncBinding(ObservableValue<T> original) {
    super();
    this.original = original;
    changeListener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        Runnable job = () -> {
            value = newValue; // make sure the value on the application thread is the new value
            for (InvalidationListener listener : invalidationListeners) {
                listener.invalidated(obs);
            }
            for (ChangeListener<? super T> listener : changeListeners) {
                listener.changed(obs, oldValue, newValue);
            }
        };
        Platform.runLater(job);
    };
    original.addListener(changeListener);
}

...

@Override
public T getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

This way the value should be updated ***eventually***. This could take a while however, since you're doing 1000000 `Platform.runLater` calls which could take a while to complete freezing the application until it's done.

Comment: My guess would be that "after some time" is at the point where the number of iterations of the loop meets the threshold where the JIT compiler compiles the repetitive code. Just a guess though.